# Reliability of (SFTP or WebDAV) with FUSE

Tags: sftp, cloud, webdav, fuse, gcsfuse

I want to mount a Google Cloud Storage bucket as a network drive on my laptop using FUSE and SFTP or WebDAV.  Can I use SMB or Samba?

From time to time, I may run a differencing and merging tool (aka folder comparison and synchronization).  I would be using file size and time stamp.

Is this just a bad idea?

Consider that if I were to rename a folder with 1000 files, then this would mean 1000 file rename instructions going to the server.  Commands traveling over long distances... my experience with the internet, is that sometimes packets get dropped.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse

Is it more reliable to run a VPS at Google Cloud to handle the FUSE part?  More reliable than software like WebDrive, NetDrive, Mountain Duck, Expandrive, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As no one has responded, I still don't know the answer to these questions.  But I think I can rely on others who are developing free and open source software for sync/backup purposes.

I am going to try running Duplicati or Syncthing, on a VM instance, such as Amazon EZ2, or Google Cloud Compute.  I believe this is the answer to my question.  Feel free to upvote or downvote this answer if you just don't feel like posting an actual answer.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since Google Cloud Storage is not a filesystem (is binary object storage), I think that is not the correct approach abuse of Fuse SW, i don't know if some constraint in the SW side could affect the reliability or the performance.

I think that  [Google Cloud Filestore(GCF)](https://cloud.google.com/filestore) could be a product that fit better with this use case.

GCF works as Network drive using nfs protocol, this offers the same flexibility  as working with a regular drive or directory.